# How to convert CMSampleBufferRef to UIIMage

Tags: ios, objective-c

No solution is working which I found on the internet to convert CMSampleBufferRef to UIIMage.

I need a screenshot of it.

```html
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer *displayLayer;

- (void)handleSampleBufferRef:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer {
        [self.displayLayer enqueueSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
}
```

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383932/convert-cmsamplebufferref-to-uiimage

Comment: Yes, @Qudeq1, I tried that one. It create nil image. Is there any other solution?